# python : strange str.contains behaviour

Tags: python, string, pandas

i have a dataframe named df as df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')

```
    CUSTOMER_MAILID                       EVENT_GENRE       EVENT_LANGUAGE  
0   000.tushar@gmail.com                    |ROMANCE|          Hindi   
1   000.tushar@gmail.com                      |DRAMA|          TAMIL   
2        satya@gmail.com                    |ROMANCE|          Hindi   
3   000.tushar@gmail.com                      |DRAMA|          Hindi   
4          sat@gmail.com    |ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|        English   
5   000.tushar@gmail.com    |ACTION|ADVENTURE|COMEDY|        English   
6       fdvklf@gmail.com                     |ACTION|          Hindi   
7        asdar@gmail.com                      |DRAMA|          Hindi   
8       dfvkme@gmail.com     |FANTASY|HORROR|ROMANCE|        English   
9   000.tushar@gmail.com  |ACTION|ADVENTURE|THRILLER|        English   
10        king@gmail.com                      |DRAMA|          Hindi   
11  000.tushar@gmail.com           |ROMANCE|THRILLER|        KANNADA   
12  000.tushar@gmail.com                      |DRAMA|          Hindi   
13  000.tushar@gmail.com     |ACTION|ADVENTURE|DRAMA|        English   
14      iamher@gmail.com     |ACTION|ADVENTURE|DRAMA|         TELUGU   
15  000.tushar@gmail.com               |BIOPIC|DRAMA|          Hindi   
16    0007ayan@gmail.com            |HORROR|THRILLER|          Hindi   
17    0007ayan@gmail.com     |ACTION|COMEDY|THRILLER|           ODIA   
18  000.tushar@gmail.com    |ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI|        English   
19    0007ayan@gmail.com                    |ROMANCE|          Hindi
```

But when i was querying i found some discrepancy in the sense the str.contains does not returned me the expected output.

```
 d = df.query((df['EVENT_GENRE'].str.contains('|ROMANCE|')) & (df['EVENT_LANGUAGE'] == 'Hindi'))
 d
 Out[53]: 
     CUSTOMER_MAILID        EVENT_GENRE EVENT_LANGUAGE
 0   000.tushar@gmail.com          |ROMANCE|          Hindi
 2        satya@gmail.com          |ROMANCE|          Hindi
 3   000.tushar@gmail.com            |DRAMA|          Hindi
 6       fdvklf@gmail.com           |ACTION|          Hindi
 7        asdar@gmail.com            |DRAMA|          Hindi
 10        king@gmail.com            |DRAMA|          Hindi
 12  000.tushar@gmail.com            |DRAMA|          Hindi
 15  000.tushar@gmail.com     |BIOPIC|DRAMA|          Hindi
 16    0007ayan@gmail.com  |HORROR|THRILLER|          Hindi
 19    0007ayan@gmail.com          |ROMANCE|          Hindi
```

As you can see EVENT_GENRE field contains no 'ROAMNCE', but when i am doing without '|' ex. '|ROMANCE|' to 'ROMANCE',  i am getting the expected output.

```
d = df.query((df['EVENT_GENRE'].str.contains('ROMANCE')) & (df['EVENT_LANGUAGE'] == 'Hindi'))

d
Out[55]: 
     CUSTOMER_MAILID EVENT_GENRE EVENT_LANGUAGE
0   000.tushar@gmail.com   |ROMANCE|          Hindi
2        satya@gmail.com   |ROMANCE|          Hindi
19    0007ayan@gmail.com   |ROMANCE|          Hindi
```

Then i tried for different scenario with '|' (strange result found) and without('|') (expected result found).

I am just curious if '|' symbol has some effect on str.contains() method.I highly doubt it behaves like "or" operation. Bcoz when i tried with

```
dd = df.query(df['EVENT_GENRE'].str.contains('FANTASY|HORROR'))

dd
Out[21]: 
       CUSTOMER_MAILID               EVENT_GENRE EVENT_LANGUAGE  
8     dfvkme@gmail.com  |FANTASY|HORROR|ROMANCE|        English   
16  0007ayan@gmail.com         |HORROR|THRILLER|          Hindi
```

As it seems it treats FANTASY and HORROR with "or" operation.***NOT SURE

And with dd = df.query(df['EVENT_GENRE'].str.contains('|FANTASY|HORROR|'))   it select all data.

As of my knowledge inside a strind all included in '' or "" treated as char only(except \t,\r,\n).But i did not know if logical operators ever worked in same way(as many times i have seen & inside a string).

Can anybody please clarify that.Thanks in Adv.

Comment: The answers seems to be ok. But (for the sake of future time travelers) could you point out what library are you using? Add the tag, because it certainly *is* relevant (the `str` built-in has no attribute `contains`, and I was utterly confused).

Comment: @MariusSiuram-are you suggesting me to remove string tag from my question????

Comment: I am suggesting to add whatever is `read_csv` from

Comment: maybe it is pandas? I don't know what abbreviates `pd`, and your `str` seems mysterious to me.

Comment: @MariusSiuram-there is no point of downvote ...as clearly from description it is "python "  and my first line reads DataFrame which means it is pandas module of python...( and dask is known to comparatively less people )..BUt next time i will take care of those points.

Comment: Much better! :) (Ninja edit: Remember: there is a lot of people out there using Python __a lot__ who have never used pandas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `contains` treats your string as a regex to match against the strings.  So your `"|ROMANCE|"` is treated as a regex.  Since the first and last alternates are empty (i.e., there is nothing before the first `|` or after the last), it can match the empty string, so it always matches.

You can pass the `regex=False` argument to `contains` to force it to match only your literal string.

Comment: @BrenBarn-how/where you suggest to put regex=False inside df.query()..  As i tried dd = df.query(df['EVENT_GENRE'].str.contains('|ROMANCE|'), regex=False) got an error as TypeError: eval() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'..

Comment: This works fine...dd = df.query(df['EVENT_GENRE'].str.contains('|ROMANCE|',regex=False))

Answer (score 2):

Because `|` is a special character and you'll need to escape it with `\` symbol:

```
In [255]: df[df.EVENT_GENRE.str.contains('\|ROMANCE\|')]
Out[255]:
         CUSTOMER_MAILID               EVENT_GENRE EVENT_LANGUAGE
0   000.tushar@gmail.com                 |ROMANCE|          Hindi
2        satya@gmail.com                 |ROMANCE|          Hindi
8       dfvkme@gmail.com  |FANTASY|HORROR|ROMANCE|        English
11  000.tushar@gmail.com        |ROMANCE|THRILLER|        KANNADA
19    0007ayan@gmail.com                 |ROMANCE|          Hindi
```

Comment: Simpler to just turn regex off rather than having to escape everything in the string.

Comment: @BrenBarn yeah, but for that case it less typing.. :)